# Merge Oracle groups output into 1 single row as final result

Tags: sql, oracle

In the following select:

```
select col1, count(1) 
  from test_db.new_arch 
 where name like 'DATA1%' 
    or name like 'DUAL%'
group by col1
```

the results will be ...

```
DATA1    10
DUAL2    11
```

I would like to merge them to make them look like this:

```
DB_QUERY1  21
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `group by` to get an aggregation of one row for the entire result set:

```
select 'DB_QUERY1', count(1)
from test_db.new_arch
where name like 'DATA1%' or name like 'DUAL%';
```

Comment: it worked great, thanks Gordon, never needed something like that.